# AJAX: dynamically loading data from the same php in separate calls ok?

Tags: php, ajax, performance

I have an HTML/PHP/JQUERY/MYSQL web application. 
It's an HTML Bootstrap base, and jquery and other libraries plus my custom scripts, in front.

backend, i have several php files to serve the data.

For this example, say I have a CONTACTS php page where I need to display several data sets: 
1) List of contacts
2) List of groups 
3) list of tags associated with contacts

I have a backend php file in: engine/contacts.php

this is the php script that serves the contacts data as requested based on GET flags, eg:

```
engine/contacts.php?list=contacts
engine/contacts.php?list=groups
engine/contacts.php?list=tags
```

Sure i could serve them up in one call but , by design, each part of the web page (contacts, or groups, or tags) are separate datasets, and this way, if one data set is updated, i can refresh that part only.. eg:
user adds a group , then JS will ajax load:

```
engine/contacts.php?list=groups
```

to update the groups area (div)

So, basically, ON PAGE LOAD  3 separate JS calls are fired at the same time load data from the same contacts.php file

IS THIS AN OK Practice? I mean it should be because I see lots of sites doing the same .

And how does this impact the server side? Will the server execute this php file one at a time? will it be better if i separate the files? like:

```
contacts.php
contacts_groups.php
contacts_tags.php
```

and simultaneously call them?

The reason I ask is because I'm currently debugging some performance issues. Simply put, i have very light weight PHP/MYSQL web application with HTML5/Jquery front end. The datasets being handled is very minimal and the database tables having less than 50rows

But somehow my application is hitting resource limits on the shared host server, particularly on the 1GB RAM limit side. And i have reproduced this situation on a stand alone domain w/ no other users and it's still hitting the limits.

I have gone through the php scripts and can't find anything. I do have loops, yes, but they are thoughtfully done and terminates after a few iterations.

I'm out of ideas so I'm just trying to explore what else i can poke at.

Would appreciate some guidance, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you use an OOP structure you can consider a method for handling each request in backend. Although the best way is to use a MVC framework to dispatch the requests with URL routing to special methods :

```
    engine/contacts/contacts
    engine/contacts/groups
    engine/contacts/tags
```

Comment: tnx but that is to the same effect.. it's just a different way of calling it. both your suggest and my use is actually based on the MVC principle and both methods still hits that one php file 3 times to serve 3 different data sets ... so my question is, MVC or not, is this single file data source hit 3 times heavier to the server comparing to hitting 3 different files instead, or even hitting 1 php script that serves all that data (same load in the back end, same queries, same loops)

Comment: It's not different at all! Every request to server run an instance of your application and take some particular time for serving and doesn't care about the source location in your project.